# shift in getopts loop - clarification needed

Tags: shell, getopts

I would be glad if someone clarified the need to use `shift` in this simple parser code:

```
while getopts ":hp:" option
do
    case "${option}" in
        p)
            some_parameter=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        h)
            print_usage_and_exit 0
            ;;
        *)
            print_usage_and_exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done

shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))
```

For instance, it is unclear to me:

1. Why is there seemingly no need for a `shift` inside the loop?

   Does accessing `getopts` move the arguments on itself, or how does it work?
2. Why is there a need for a `shift` after `getopts`?

   I don't get why would not `getopts` do that by itself at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don’t need to `shift` (and shouldn’t) inside the loop because `getopts` tracks which positional parameter it’s processing by updating the `OPTIND` variable.
2. You don’t *need* to `shift` after the loop: you can use `OPTIND` to determine which positional parameters to handle yourself. Using `shift` however is the simplest way of dealing with arguments which have been processed by `getopts`, assuming you don’t need to post-process them yourself.

Having `getopts` *not* shift itself has a couple of benefits: you can revisit arguments yourself if necessary, and you can reproduce the original command line. The latter is useful for example in error messages, or if you need to run another command with the same arguments (I know I’ve used that in the past).

Comment: Shifting, as shown, after the loop will ensure that `"$@"` only contains the non-option arguments to the script/function.

Comment: @Kusalananda I assumed, perhaps incorrectly, that the OP understood that.